# Listing 10.9 from programming in scala

Tags: scala, inheritance, abstract-class

I was going through Chapter 10(Composition and Inheritance) from "Programming in Scala" and I am a little confused by the code-listing 10.9. The author has the code listing as follows:

```
abstract class Element{
  def contents:Array[String]
  def width: Int = if(height==0)0elsecontents(0).length
  def height: Int = contents.length
  def above(that: Element): Element =
      new ArrayElement(this.contents ++ that.contents)
  def beside(that: Element): Element=
              new ArrayElement(
                 for(
                   (line1, line2)<-this.contents zip that.contents
                ) yield line1+line2
              )
  override def toString = contents mkString "\n"
}
```

My confusion is with the methods "above" and "beside", these methods are instantiating a sub-class ArrayElement, from the abstract base class Element. Is this actually correct or I am missing something here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you are correct.  There must be some class `AbstractElement` defined as a subclass of `Element`.  These two methods are instantiating this class and returning the newly instantiated object.

Comment: ... There must be some class **Element** as a **superclass** of **ArrayElement**...